# В android studio использую одновременно 2 библиотеки okhttp3 и paho mqtt и функции okhttp3 перестают работать

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, mqtt

В android studio использую одновременно 2 библиотеки okhttp3 и paho mqtt и функции okhttp3 перестают работать.

Может делать временное отключение mqtt? Когда идет обращение по okhttp.

Comment: Может, у вас конфликт версий OkHttp? Не имел дела с mqtt, зависит ли эта библиотека от OkHttp? Посмотрите дерево зависимостей в вашем проекте. (Например, если вы используете gradle и android, то выполните комнаду `./gradlew app:dependencies`)

Comment: Спасибо, принял.